# How Can I use multiple id in one selector I have applied it but not working

Tags: jquery

```
$("#frontpage-course-list" || "#frontpage-category-names" || "#frontpage-category-combo" || "#site-news-forum").append("<a id='clps' class='clps-cls'><img src='<?php echo $CFG->wwwroot ?>/theme/elfin28/pix/images/course-plus.png' /></a>");
```

I would like to add multiple id in one selector. I have applied it but not working. How can I do this in this code.

Comment: Use `,` - `$('#id1, #id2')` **[Multiple Selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)**

Comment: Use comma seperator for multiselector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below code. use comma separator not ||   . read more about [Multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

check **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/scdb6amh/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#frontpage-course-list,#frontpage-category-names,#frontpage-category-combo,#site-news-forum").append("<a id='clps' class='clps-cls'><img src='<?php echo $CFG->wwwroot ?>/theme/elfin28/pix/images/course-plus.png' /></a>");
});
```

Comment: $('#clps').click(function() {
 $('.frontpage-course-list-all, .frontpage-category-names, .course_category_tree, .forumpost').slideToggle('slow');
 return false;
 
 });

Comment: @KabirKhan why you add return false?

Comment: @KabirKhan can you please add your HTML code or create fiddle ?

Comment: Yes, it's working, now I am using comma in different code. plz check my comment code.